# Can I mount a SDcard READER in fstab?

Tags: fstab, automounting

I'm new to linux, bought an hp stream 11, and downloaded arch to maximize use of this craptop.  I got a sd card for Personal File storage mounted as /home.  I wish to use multiple cards that i can just swap out easily if i want to access the files or space on a different card, and i want it to automatically mount any sd card inserted to the same directory.  It seems like you'd need to somehow mount the reader in the fstab rather than the sd cards to achieve this, is this correct?  Either way, how would you accomplish this?

Comment: I believe mounting to /media might do just that, maybe those directory binders can help accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably don't want to mount it as `/home`, unless I misunderstand what you're trying to do: Linux expects `/home/yourUsername/` to be the parent directory for all your user-specific files,  e.g. the shell script that runs whenever you log in, and I suspect hot-swapping `/home` would cause problems.

I believe the default behavior in most GUI Linux systems on inserting an SD card would be to mount it on a sub-directory of `/media` named to reflect the filesystem on the card (e.g. `/media/my-sd-card/`). Would that be sufficient, or is there some reason that you need any SD card you insert to be mounted on the same path?

Also, you probably can't mount your sd-card *reader*, unless it exports a file-system without any card in it, which would be very unusual.

Comment: The laptop has 32GB of storage which i'm saving for program files and swap space for speed reasons.  The SD card is 200GB and will hold all of my personal files.  Being new to linux, I chose to mount it as /home.  It's kinda nice, the pc requires the sd card to start (somewhat like a key) and holds what i'd want to keep private.  I put it in my wallet in a credit card sized holder when i power the laptop off.  I would like to be able to utilize more sd cards for storage if necessary.  Maybe I can clone the necessary user files on each sd card?  I'd like to be able to use blank sd cards though.